# False return of 1 on COUNTA with FILTER

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to make a sheet to count the number of instances of data and certain responses are going to be grouped together. I am having problems coming up with the three formulas correctly. Here are my best guesses along with some English to help clarify what I am trying to accomplish.

```
//Count all cells that are Warrior or Paladin [Always returns 1, and not zero]
=COUNTA(FILTER(I:I, OR(I:I="Warrior", I:I="Paladin")))

//Count all cells that are Scholar or White Mage [Always returns 1, and not zero]
=COUNTA(FILTER(I:I, OR(I:I="Scholar", I:I="White Mage")))

//Count all cells that are do not all within the first sets of requirements [Always returns 1, not 2]
=COUNTA(FILTER(I:I, NOT(OR(I:I="Warrior", I:I="Paladin", I:I="Scholar", I:I="White Mage"))))
```

The two cells are Monk and Summoner. Any help would be appreciated

Edit: [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10IxILjP7xzO6NqwaWsbfW250z23QLicx5rWiej9GDIg/edit#gid=0) is a sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you share a public spreadsheet?

Comment: I have search for how to properly implement filter and counta at the same time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At least two issues:

1. OR can't be iterated over an array in an array expression; you will need to use the + operand instead.
2. FILTER will return #N/A if there is no output, and COUNTA will count this error value as 1. Hence when 0 is expected, you get 1; use IFERROR to account for this.

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(I:I,(I:I="Warrior")+(I:I="Paladin"))))`

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(I:I,(I:I="Scholar")+(I:I="White Mage"))))`

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(I:I,I:I<>"Warrior",I:I<>"Paladin",I:I<>"Scholar",I:I<>"White Mage")))`

Alternatives to the first and third formulae that are more easily extendible:

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(I:I,MATCH(I:I,{"Warrior";"Paladin"},0))))`

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(I:I,ISERROR(MATCH(I:I,{"Warrior";"Paladin";"Scholar";"White Mage"},0)))))`